# how can I properly free memory when using libproc

Tags: c++, c

I followed example on http://ewencumming.blogspot.cz/2012/02/list-processes-using-libproc.html in order to browse running processes on linux kernel. However I discovered that code has a leak:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <proc/readproc.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
 // fillarg used for cmdline
 // fillstat used for cmd
 PROCTAB* proc = openproc(PROC_FILLARG | PROC_FILLSTAT);

 proc_t proc_info;

 // zero out the allocated proc_info memory
 memset(&proc_info, 0, sizeof(proc_info));

 while (readproc(proc, &proc_info) != NULL) { // <<!!!!!! here is the leak !!!!!!
  // do something
 }

 closeproc(proc);
}
```

running this code (whole main) in a loop is allocating memory but it doesn't free it.

According to comment in source of libproc freeproc() should be called somewhere, but calling it anywhere just crash the application (it should be called when readproc buffer return NULL).

How can I properly release the memory allocated by readproc? (The library is in c but code I am writing is in c++ so I am tagging both)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the manpage](http://manned.org/readproc.3):

> readproc reads the information for the next process matching the criteria specified in `PT` and fills them into a `proc_t` structure. **If `return_buf` is not `NULL`, it will use the struct pointed at by `return_buf`. Otherwise it will allocate a new `proc_t` structure and return a pointer to it. Note that (if so specified in `PT`) `readproc` always allocates memory if it fills in the `environ` or `cmdline` parts of `proc_t`.**
>
> `freeproc` frees all memory allocated for the `proc_t` struct `*p`.

You're using `PROC_FILLARG` which "fills in the `cmdline` part of `proc_t`, so the final bolded sentence is activated. This means the struct is allocated by `readproc`, but you're ignoring the return value in which a pointer to this struct can be found; this struct is different from the one you're using, and later trying to free — never free an object with automatic storage duration ("on the stack")! That's why you're getting a crash.

You should assign the return value of `return_buf` to a pointer, and use that:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
 // fillarg  used for cmdline
 // fillstat used for cmd
 PROCTAB* proc = openproc(PROC_FILLARG | PROC_FILLSTAT);

 while (proc_t* proc_info = readproc(proc, NULL)) {
    // do something
    freeproc(proc_info)
 }

 closeproc(proc);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, just to understand this better, if I actually did a free on that proc_info.cmdline, would it solve the issue as well?

Comment: Also, I am not sure if your code is correct, readproc() has no candidate with 1 argument only, I suppose you meant while (readproc(proc, proc_info) != NULL) ?

Comment: anyway, using readproc(proc, proc_info) alway put NULL into proc_info :( to it doesn't work either...

Comment: apparently proc_info = readproc(proc, NULL) seems to work :-) I am just stupid

Comment: @Petr: Oops I meant that, yes. [This is why edit review doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2403159): your edit suggestion was 100% valid.